# Output length mismatch in nested loops?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, nested-loops

I got a problem with the number of outputs from the loop.

```
neighbours=[]#this array will hold the distance to the k-th neighbour

for i in range(0, len(selection)-1):#208 values in selection

      n2 =[]#this array will hold the distance to all the other 207 points
      for k in range(0, len(selection)-1):

          d = {}
          if i != k:#to remove the same point being considered
              ra_diff = selection[i]['ra']-selection[k]['ra']
              dec_diff= selection[i]['dec']-selection[k]['dec']
              d=float(math.hypot(ra_diff , dec_diff))#finds the distance
              n2.append(d)  
      n2.sort()
      neighbours.append(n2[6])#passes the 7th value to the array
```

This is a part of code to find a k-nearest neighbour. The selection has 208 values, the nested loop should calculate the distance to all the points and find the 7th closest point to each point.

After the iteration the neighbours array only holds 207 values(i.e. len(neighbours)=207), but there should be 7th closest neighbour for all the 208 values. 
Can anyone please point to me where the problem is?

Comment: sorry-the indent is formatted correctly now.

Comment: what is the value of `selection` variable?

Comment: selection variable has 208 values of position.

Comment: This probably isn't directly relevant to the problem you're having, but a more Pythonic way of iterating over all the unique pairs of values from a list is to use `itertools.combinations`. The code `for a, b in itertools.combinations(selection, 2):` could replace most of your current looping logic.

Comment: @Blckknght I second that the OPs code could be more pythonic,especially by not iterating over indices that are only ever used as indices, but I don't think `itertools.combinations` will do the trick, since the outer loop does extra processing on the result of the inner loop. Instead, I would put the distance calculation function and then use `heapq.nsmallest` with a generator expression.

Comment: @firefly consider posting your code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @lvc: Your right that the algorithm presented won't translate directly, but there's probably some sort of equivalent that would work. I'm not sure I understand what the code was trying to calculate (the distance from each point to the seventh-closest other point?), or I'd try to write it up as an answer.

Comment: @Blckknght this was meant to calculate the distance to the 7th nearest neighbour in order to do a surface density plot to identify galaxy clusters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
for i in range(0, len(selection)-1):
```

and

```
for k in range(0, len(selection)-1):
```

are probably the problems, `range` is exclusive of the stop parameter so the `- 1` is missing the last element.

eg.

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3]
>>> range(len(L)) # goes from 0 to N - 1, where N is len(L)
[0, 1, 2]
```

but

```
>>> range(len(L) - 1) # goes from 0 to N - 2
[0, 1]
```

Comment: I think it fixes it, when -1 is removed it gives 208 values.